# TextBox Insertion not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am at a total loss here! Perhaps someone will see something that I'm missing. I'm using this same code else where and it works just fine. The purpose is to seed an Edit mode FromView with data that I want to supply for the user.  In this case I'm not allowing user to change the information that I'm supplying.

What I get when I try to run this is:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object.

My code behind checks for null reference so I'm not sure what I can do to correct this. And this works elsewhere in my code (variables different of course).

Here is a fragment from the aspx page and then the C# code behind that go with it.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="RejectDetailPnl" Visible="false">
<asp:Button ID="RejectBtn" runat="server" OnClick="RejectBtn_Click" BackColor="#ff0000" ForeColor="#ffffff" Text="Click To Reject" />
<asp:FormView ID="RejSubmittFV" runat="server" OnInit="RejSubmittFV_Init" DefaultMode="Edit" DataSourceID="RejSubmitDS">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        CAssetID:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("CAssetID") %>' runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" ReadOnly="true" ID="CAssetIDTextBox" /><br />
        Reason:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Reason") %>' runat="server" ID="ReasonTextBox" Width="500" Height="500" TextMode="MultiLine" OnTextChanged="ReasonTextBox_TextChanged" /><br />
        Source:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Source") %>' runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" ReadOnly="true" ID="SourceTextBox" /><br />
        RejBy:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("RejBy") %>' runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" ReadOnly="true" ID="RejByTextBox" /><br />
        RejDT:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("RejDT") %>' runat="server" BackColor="LightGray" ReadOnly="true" ID="RejDTTextBox" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" o CommandName="Update" ID="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        CAssetID:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("CAssetID") %>' runat="server" ID="CAssetIDTextBox" /><br />
        Reason:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Reason") %>' runat="server" ID="ReasonTextBox" /><br />
        Source:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Source") %>' runat="server" ID="SourceTextBox" /><br />
        RejBy:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("RejBy") %>' runat="server" ID="RejByTextBox" /><br />
        RejDT:
        <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("RejDT") %>' runat="server" ID="RejDTTextBox" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        CAssetID:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("CAssetID") %>' runat="server" ID="CAssetIDLabel" /><br />
        Reason:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Reason") %>' runat="server" ID="ReasonLabel" /><br />
        Source:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Source") %>' runat="server" ID="SourceLabel" /><br />
        RejBy:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("RejBy") %>' runat="server" ID="RejByLabel" /><br />
        RejDT:
        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("RejDT") %>' runat="server" ID="RejDTLabel" /><br />
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ID="EditButton" CausesValidation="False" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="RejSubmitDS" ConnectionString="Data Source=gbaptccsr01;Initial Catalog=CInTracDB;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT CAssetID, Reason, Source, RejBy, RejDT FROM RejFailCtrl WHERE (CAssetID = @CAssetID)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE RejFailCtrl SET Reason = @Reason, Source = @Source, RejBy = @RejBy, RejDT = @RejDT WHERE (CAssetID = @CAssetID)">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:SessionParameter SessionField="ChangeRecord" Name="CAssetID"></asp:SessionParameter>
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Reason"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="Source"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="RejBy"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="RejDT"></asp:Parameter>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CAssetID"></asp:Parameter>
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="RejectResetBtn" Visible="false" OnClick="RejectResetBtn_Click" Text="*** After Entering your Comment Click this bar!! ****" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Red" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The C# code behind and the choke point is:

```
TextBox uname = (TextBox)RejSubmittFV.Row.FindControl("RejByTextBox");
```

There are two other points I have tested by commenting out sections that also fail in this code block. Basically every time I repeat this code sequence it renders this error. Here is the full code block for your reference:

```
protected void RejectBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox uname = (TextBox)RejSubmittFV.Row.FindControl("RejByTextBox");
if (uname != null)
    uname.Text = Session["RegUser"].ToString();

TextBox usource = (TextBox)RejSubmittFV.Row.FindControl("SourceTextBox");
if (usource != null)
    usource.Text = "CInTrac";

TextBox udate = (TextBox)RejSubmittFV.Row.FindControl("RejDTTextBox");
if (udate != null)
udate.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Like I mentioned this procedure is working perfectly elsewhere so I don't have a clue why it isn't here.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciate!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `FormView` Control, but I don't think it has rows. What happens when you use `TextBox uname = (TextBox)RejSubmittFV.FindControl("RejByTextBox");`

Comment: That breaks the control... the row is required.... seems silly but it is.

Comment: I've copied your code and fiddled with it a bit. Is `Session["RegUser"]` initiated somewhere before it is used? If not you'll get the same error.

Comment: I've eliminated that block and ran it with just the next one that assigns the value of "CInTrac" to usoruce that also fails ... also RegUser is an active session var I use it in the same page elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never came up with a real answer for this issue! What I ended up doing to work around the problem was to eliminate the ForrView and simple sit the 5 data fields in a panel that I controlled the visibility with by ID which eliminated the issue of having to navigate the `FindControl`. This lead to abandoning the `SqlDataSource` and doing my update via a stored procedure and 100% with code behind and it was a LOT cleaner as a result.

```
// Update the Control file 
SqlConnection UpdRejConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GBAPTCCSR01;Initial Catalog=CInTracDB;Integrated Security=True");

SqlCommand Updcmd = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader Updreader;

Updcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAssetID", Session["ChangeRecord"]);
Updcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reason", ReasonTextBox.Text.ToString());
Updcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rejby", RejByTextBox.Text.ToString());
Updcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Source", SourceTextBox.Text.ToString());
Updcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RejDT", RejDTTextBox.Text.ToString());

Updcmd.CommandText = "usp_UpdRejCtrl";
Updcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
Updcmd.Connection = UpdRejConnection;

UpdRejConnection.Open();
Updreader = Updcmd.ExecuteReader();
UpdRejConnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing two items that could be null which you are expecting to exist:

1. `RejSubmittFV` and the `.Row` property.  They're not assigned, in the code you've provided, so we cannot be sure that you're initializing that object.
2. `Session["RegUser"]` which isn't tested for null before you're trying to call `.ToString()` on it.

If you're able to step through with a debugger, these are the kinds of operations to look for.  You can either add a watch to these values or you can simply hover your mouse and see if each reference is null.

Comment: .Row is a filler here as TextBox has no rows unlike gridviews it is a bit of an anomaly of the controls but is required.  As I mentioned this structure does work and is on the same page further up working fine with exactly the same syntax. In addition, that same session  var is used as well and is not null as it is displaying data to the screen just prior to the error and there is nothing in the code to wipe the value of the variable.

Comment: Back from holiday weekend... still no resolution on this one.